# How to display date time in format 2018-06-25T07:17:17.000Z?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I want to display the datetime in the following format using **python**: `2018-06-25T07:17:17.000Z`

I am trying to convert using `strftime`:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dTH:M:SZ")
```

but it seems that doesn't work.
What i am missing?

Comment: How about `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` ?

Comment: You are missing the `%` before `%H:%M:%S%Z`

Comment: Oh come on, i am missing % .Sorry and thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2018-06-25T07:17:17.000Z

This format is called ISO format, after standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The datetime object has a [isoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) method to output this form.

> strftime("%Y-%m-%dTH:M:SZ")

You seem to have forgotten some `%` before the H, M, and S. Try `strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`.

> but it seems that doesn't work.

Generally it works better if you specify exactly what doesn't work, or what you expect and how the reality differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.today().isoformat()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following formating for date conversion.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
'2018-06-25T15:50:18.313620Z'
```

Please let me know,if this is the one you needed.